# fatal error: SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, windows, sfml, mingw

При попытке скомпилировать тестовый код на SFML вылазит ошибка из названия - fatal error: SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory
Я работаю в Dev-Cpp, с компилятором MinGW 7.3.0. SFML также скачана под этот компилятор. Настройки следующие

- Параметры

  - Linker

    ```
    -lsfml-audio
    -lsfml-graphics
    -lsfml-window
    -lsfml-system
    ```
- Файлы/Каталоги

  - Библиотек

    - `C:\Program Files (x86)\SFML\lib`
  - Файлов включения

    - `C:\Program Files (x86)\SFML\include`

Директория C:\Program Files (x86)\SFML\ существует. Заголовок в файле - `#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>`
Что пошло не так?

Comment: ¿А файл `C:\Program Files (x86)\SFML\include\SFML\Graphics.hpp` существует?

Comment: @user7860670 да